# Urllib not reading entire page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib

I have been trying to use urllib.request to read a webpage. The problem I found though was that at least in some instances urllib wasn't able to read the whole page. By this I mean that it returned some html-text but not all that was on the webpage. Can anyone explain why this happens and what you can do instead? An example of my code, the way I used it is here:

```
import urllib.request

open = urllib.request.urlopen('http://SomeSite.com')
page = open.read()
```

Comment: Check if desired page has iframe?

Comment: Checked it and it doesn't.

Comment: Is it possible to add the url of the site?

Comment: It is but I think I have figured it out already, it seems that they have hidden a part of their site from web scraping. So it has nothing to do with the code just that particular site. But anyways thank you very much for your time!